# Spock Mock Object to return an object passed into it

Tags: java, spock

I'm trying to test a service implementation that handles conversion and persistence.

I have a repository mocked and and a conversion service wired in. 
Is it possible in Spock to have a Mock pass back the object that was returned to it?

The syntax I am trying to write would be as follows.

i.e.

```
// Have this method return the object that has been passed to it.
repository.save(_ as Entity) >> (Entity) _
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the the section [computing return values](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_computing_return_values) of the Spock documentation for more details, but this would do what you want to accomplish.

```
repository.save(_ as Entity) >> { args -> args[0] }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Just needed the right term to look up in the docs. Thanks!